# Is there a ? ("safe operator") alternative in Typescript to deal with null values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my Angular app, I'm trying to show/hide a div using `ngIf`.

Below is my HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="damageReportToPolice()">
</div>
```

And here is my typescript:

```
public damageReportToPolice(): boolean {      
 if(this.damageDetailsTwoForm['controls'].injuryTypeGp['controls'].injuryType.value.value === 'Burglary in the car') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

This is working fine when the page loads, & when the condition is true the div is displaying.

But, when I `reset()` the form, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

When I had this conditional in my HTML, I was able to use `?` as a safe operator like so:

```
damageDetailsTwoForm['controls'].injuryTypeGp.controls.injuryType?.value?.value === 'Burglary in the car'
```

But I can't seem to find a typescript alternative to this.

Can someone please tell me if there's a *safe operator* I can use? Or how I can get around this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, that's named **elvis operator** (Ref. Kotlin) and it's also a [javascript proposal](https://dev.to/sammyisa/optional-chaining-may-be-coming-to-javascript--4ff0) that could come out in next ES specifications. There's no a short solution for typescript/javascript, if you don't want to chain it like

```
injuryType && injuryType.value && injuryType.value.value
```

then you can just create a function that returns `null` in case of exception:

```
export function safeNavigation(cb) {
  try {
    return cb();
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};




// In the component...
if (safeNavigation(() => injuryType.value.value) === 'Burglary in the car') {
...
```

PS. If it doesn't casue conflicts, I like to rename it as `_` and use it like `_(() => path.to.navigate)`